# Как возвращать файлы с русскими буквами в названии через FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Сделал на FastAPI сервис, который возвращает файл по ссылке.
Примитивно выглядит так:

```
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException    
from starlette.responses import FileResponse    


app = FastAPI()
db = DataBase(config=CONFIG.mysql)

@app.get('/v1.0/get_file')
async def get_file(id_file: str):
    # ...
    file = db.get_file(id_file)
    # ...        
    return FileResponse(file.path, filename=file.file_name)
```

Пока `file.file_name` не содержит русских символов, файл успешно скачивается. Как только там появляются русские буквы, мой код падает с ошибкой:

```
 ...
 File
 "/home/servicemanager/services/file_service/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/datastructures.py",
 line 606, in setdefault
     set_value = value.encode("latin-1")
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 22-26: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Не понимаю, откуда вообще берется подобная ошибка. У меня все в кодировке utf-8. Я предположил, что возможно мне БД возвращает что-то не в той кодировке, но даже если я явно пишу вызов `FileResponse(file.path, filename='отчет.xlsx')` мой код все равно возвращает ошибку. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в происходящем.

Comment: [RFC 5987](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987) и [URL Quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev моих знаний не достаточно, чтобы интерпретировать эту ссылку. Дайте, пожалуйста, чуть более развернутый комментарий

Comment: Эту проблему [исправили 11 дней назад](https://github.com/encode/starlette/commit/1e406655fe82a5b89c3b39884a1de5779d457eee). Вам нужно обновить Starlette до версии 0.13.2 и всё заработает

Comment: @andreymal все не так просто. FastApi еще не обновился, и просто "обновить Starlette" пока не получается)

Comment: Хм, fastapi зачем-то залочен на версии 0.12.9. Зря, очень зря

Comment: Я попробовал силой обновить только Starlette, но Fastapi у меня после этого не запустился =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этого должно хватить

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

...

    return FileResponse(file.path, filename=quote_plus(file.file_name))
```

Но лучше ознакомиться со стандартами кодирования в HTTP.

Comment: При этом этот ответ не соответствует вами же упомянутому RFC 5987 :)

Comment: @andreymal угу, я постарался написать максимально простое решение. На предотвращение ошибки должно хватить.